# Getting "File contains corrupted data" exception while opening the XPSDocument Package

Tags: xpsdocument, system.io.packaging

I am getting the exception within my Console Application

```
HResult -2146233033 InnerException  null 
Message File contains corrupted data. 
Source  WindowsBase SourceUri   null StackTrace    at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOEndOfCentralDirectoryBlock.FindPosition(Stream archiveStream)    at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOEndOfCentralDirectoryBlock.SeekableLoad(ZipIOBlockManager blockManager)    at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream archiveStream, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Boolean streaming, Boolean ownStream)    at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipArchive.OpenOnStream(Stream stream, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Boolean streaming)    at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream s, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Boolean streaming)    at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess, Boolean streaming)
```

Tried this looking in answers, but it did not help.

```
string xpsfilename = @"D:\test\sample_file.xps";

var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

var data = webClient.DownloadData(xpsfilename);
//var data = File.ReadAllBytes(xpsfilename);
using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
{
    var package = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(stream); /* Exception thrown here */
    var xpsDocument = new System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument(package, System.IO.Packaging.CompressionOption.SuperFast, xpsfilename);
    var sequence = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

    SaveDocumentPagesToImages(sequence, @"D:\test");
}
```